# Javascript onkeyup being fired twice sometimes

Tags: javascript

For some reason my onkeyup seems to be fired twice for some people on IE9.

My current function looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("chatboxtextarea").onkeyup=function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var msg = document.getElementById('chatboxtextarea').value;
    if(e.keyCode != null) {
        if (msg.replace(/\r/g, '\\\\r').replace(/\n/g, '') != "" && e.keyCode == 13) {
            var textarea = document.getElementById('chatboxtextarea');
            textarea.value = '';

            var d = new Date();
            var curr_hour = d.getHours();
            var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
            var tD = curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;


            var url = 'http://domain.com/sub/' + kanal + '/' + encodeURIComponent(_aNM) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(_sid) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(_aID) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(_pMsg) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(msg.replace(/\r/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '')) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(_hits);
            var data = {};
            var callback = function (data) { };
            J50Npi.getJSON(url, data, callback);                            
        } else if (msg.replace(/\r/g, '\\\\r').replace(/\n/g, '') == '') {
            var textarea = document.getElementById('chatboxtextarea');
            textarea.value = '';
        }           
    }
};
```

This is for a basic chat input field. Problem is that the server receives two messages from these IE9 users (sometimes).

How would i add a check to see if people have already written a message in the last 1 seconds? Like a spam prevention function.. i guess that would solve the problem?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible people are pressing the enter key twice fairly quickly?

Any time I have to perform an async operation, I debounce the input.

Just after your keycode == 13 check, first check to see if the textares is already disabled, if it is disabled ignore any further processing.
Second, set the textarea to disabled.
Third, remove the disabled attribute upon success of J50Npi.getJSON();

```
textarea.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
textarea.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tnwje/1/

Comment: Cant be possible that they press it twice quickly, on a whole chat conversation the person using IE9 always had exactly two identical messages instead of one